# Spark(scala): Count all distinct values of a whole column on RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this RDD:

```
val resultRdd: RDD[(VertexId, String, Seq[Long])]
```

I want to count the distinct values in Seq of all records.

for example, if I have 3 records with Seq values as follows:

```
VertexId ------- String -------Seq[Long]
1 ----------------- x -------------  1, 3
2 ----------------- x -------------  1, 5
3 ----------------- x--------------- 2, 3, 6
```

the result should be = 5 , the count of {1,3,5,2,6}

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
resultRdd.flatMap(_._3).distinct().count()
```